Chrome Version125 Breaking File Downloads (ASP.NET MVC)
After updating to the latest Chrome, my ASP.NET MVC project deployed on server computers is breaking when attempting to download/load PDF files.
I have verified this is a Chrome only issue - no issues loading the PDF on Edge or on version 124 of Chrome.
Has anyone else ran into this issue or know how to fix?
The line of code where I return the file is simple - shouldn't cause any issues:
public ActionResult PDF(Decimal? testNum)
{
    return File(db.PDFs.Where(x => x.id == testNum).Select(x => x.PDFfile).Single(), "application/pdf"); 
}

I am stumped! Any client with 124. V Chrome has no issues (or any other browser) but as of today clients who updated to 125 the entire page freezes upon the simple PDF file return... any help is much appreciated.
